# Mesh is invisible when game is played

Tags: game-engine

I am building a game that is inside a sphere mesh but whenever I launch the game the sphere is invisible from the inside but is visible from the outside. I have already tried multiple fixes but the fixes I've tried involve them happening in Blender render or blender cycle which don't effect blender game.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help resolve this issue.

Comment: Invert the normals of the sphere so they point inwards

Answer (score 1):

In the material properties under game setting was backface culling. That fixed the issue. I apologise for posting the question and then finding the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to see the sphere always from the inside (and never from the outside) I suggest to flip the face normals.

- select the sphere object
- edit mode
- <kbd>w</kbd> -> <kbd>f</kbd>Flip Normals (alternatively <kbd>shift+ctrl+n</kbd>)

Disabling Backface Culling is good on very thin objects that can be seen from both sides such as a sheet of paper, curtains, or leafs.